# Checking if a line contains a letter/number?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Using the bufferedReader, how can you check if a line contains a letter or a number?

I just thought of this at the top of my head:

```
readLine().matches("[A-Za-z0-9 ]+")
```

Would you recommend this?

Comment: Do you mean only a letter or only a number (and by number, do you mean single or multiple digits)?

Comment: in addition to Roger's question, do you mean atleast one letter/ number or do you mean just letters/ numbers ? are special characters in the lines allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the line as a String from the buffered reader, then iterate through the chars of the String, and use `Character.isLetter(char)` and `Character.isDigit(char)` to know if the current char is a letter or a digit.

All the methods of all the classes are described in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

The call to matches will return true only if the line contains **only** the characters specified by the regex. You'll need to use a Matcher and call find to detect if the STring contains one of the chars in `[A-Za-z0-9 ]`.

Note that your pattern contains a space, which is not a letter nor a digit. Also note that there are a whole loat of letters which are not in `[A-Za-z]`.